# iptables allow whm mail port 25

Tags: iptables

Trying to understand iptables (I have cPanel installed on VPS) and having a little play so may sound like a silly question what I am doing.

I have copied the default iptables config to backup (in case goes wrong to restore) and created custom iptables config (/etc/sysconfig/iptables) were I DROP INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARDING (so everything).

I then managed to get all the ports I want access to required working (incoming/outgoing HTTP/s/SSH/FTP etc) apart from emails (:25). I am using Roundcube and using the below config for emails but emails can not be sent/received on my server (works if I restore default config (ACCEPT everything) so apart from port :25 is there any other ports I need to allow access to for mail to be sent knowing everything has been dropped?). I am using below config for email in my custom (/etc/sysconfig/iptables):-

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

IP is a bidirectional communication, when you **receive** a mail, packets are sent on your server on port 25, and you will send response packet on a arbitrary allocated port number (determined during connection establishment).

So, common rule on iptables are : 
Accepting packet on input from a specified port (25 for mail) whatever the state of connection
`-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

Accepting to send back packets for all established connection whatever the destination port.`-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Now, if you want to **send** mail to a server, you have to allow packet to go out to port 25 and allow incoming all established connection.

`-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

Another idea , will be to log packets that should be dropped.
put log line a the end of all chain's rules.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT PACKET DROPPED "
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT PACKET DROPPED "
```

With that, you will see in /var/log/message (or with dmesg)  a line for each packet reaching the end of chain's rule and beeing dropped.